# Bayesian analysis - logarithmically increasing predictor, categorical outcome

Tags: r, bayesian, generalized-linear-model, references, ordinal-data

I'm new to Bayesian analysis. My *predictor* is a logarithmically increasing variable (10, 100, 1000..) and the *outcome* is a categorical variable which indicates correct/incorrect. I need to analyze this data using Bayesian analysis.

**What have I done?**

I have analyzed this data using a general linear model (GLM). I can see a linear relationship which shows that correct responses increase with length.

**What I need**

I need to develop this further using Bayesian analysis.

1. Can I treat my *predictor* as a continuous variable - I only have finite values though (10, 100, 1000...)?
2. Can I send the coefficient obtained using the GLM into the Bayesian as the likelihood?
3. What would be the assumptions needed for this to be valid? For example, should the data be transformed in a specific way?
   I have heard that this is a popular technique. I searched everywhere for 2. and 3., but couldn't find a good reference for it.

Comment: Hi Ayushi. Welcome to CV. I have edited a bit your post. Did you search here in this site for 1.? I am sure there are quite many good posts that would have addressed this.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind edits and suggestions. Really helpful. I'm looking through the website for 1., and already have an intuition about it. Many thanks! Hope to hear about the others too.